# How to connect Flink to Kafka running on a different machine?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to run my Flink jar to listen to a kafka topic, do some processing and write it back to another kafka topic. Kafka is not running on the same machine as Flink, so localhost can't be used.

Below is my code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers","notlocalhost:9093");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the ip addresses of your kafka cluster like this.
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers","ip1:9092,ip2:9092,ip3:9092");

Also its good idea to use a placeholder variable and set that variable from a config file or env variable.
public static final String KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="ip1:9092,ip2:9092,ip2:9092"

properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers",KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);